# Loading documents in middleware with projections?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My routes are set up something like this:

```
app.get('/blah/:id', middleware.middleware, controller.get);

app.post('/blah/:id', middleware.middleware, controller.update);
```

In my middleware, I load in my resource:

```
module.exports.middleware = function(req, res, next){
    Resource.findOne({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, resource){
        if (err){
            return res.status(500).json(blahblabhblaha);
        }

        if (!resource){ 
            return res.status(404).json(blahblabhblaha);
        }

        if (authorization condition fails){
            return res.status(401).json(blahblabhblaha);
        }

        //more condition checking, etc

        res.locals.resource = resource;
        return next();
    });
};
```

This is nice for me because I can handle all of the authorization and stuff in one fell swoop. It also cleans up my controllers considerably. The problem is that I can't use mongo's projections this way, because the controllers need different parts of the resource. Is there anyway I can get around this without resorting to having my controllers make database calls?

The only way I thought of getting around this was a dependency injection sort of thing,

```
module.exports.middleware = function(projection){
    return function(req, res next){
        Resource.findOne({ _id : req.params.id }, projection, function(err, resource){
         //all the other stuff above
        }
    }
}
```

The routes would become something like this:

```
app.get('/blah/:id', middleware.middleware({ foo: 1 }), controller.get);

app.post('/blah/:id', middleware.middleware({ bar: 1}), controller.update);
```

But then I have to set projections in my router, which is pretty annoying and if I change anything I need in the controller, I have to change it in it's corresponding route, which isn't that bad, but it does seem very disorganized.